# How to use the function search and replace in codemirror editor?

Tags: codemirror

I am using codemirror and I need to use the function search and replace ... I read this [here this function](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#addons)

I want to find word and replace it by another word ... I write this code but did not work :

```
  <script src="plugin/codemirror/addon/search/search.js"></script>
  <script src="plugin/codemirror/addon/search/searchcursor.js"></script>
```

here use the function :

```
   var cor= editor.getSearchCursor("one", null, null);
    cor.replace("one","anything");
```

so what wrong ? How I can call the function correct ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not just using the [`doc.replaceRange` function](https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_content)?

Comment: I did not knew doc.replaceRange is found ... I will try it ... Thanks @jeyoung

Comment: yes it work ... big thanks @jeyoung

Comment: You're very much welcome.